# Compute Cosine SImilarity Within Groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe that consists of rows like the following.  My goal here is to compute the the cosine similarity of every row with every row within the same category, such that I'd end up with a dataframe with 3 columns: category, vecs, and dist where dist is a n length array that contains the distance between each row and every row within the same category.

```
category    vecs
0   a   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
1   a   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
2   b   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
3   b   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

The inefficient solution that I've though of would be to loop through each row, check if cat is equal and then compute distance and add to list else continue loop.  This solution would be n^2 though and I'm looking for something more efficient.  I have 8115 rows in this dataframe and am looking for something that would possibly scale to even larger datasets.

The other possible solution I've looked at would be using sklearn pairwise distance (metric = cosine) and somehow only include computations with same categories, but I'm struggling to think about how to do this.

Would someone be willing to help or suggest a different efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the (more or less) n(n-1)/2 computations.
This is irreducible, since the similarities have to be computed somehow if there is no hidden structure in the vectors.

You can use scipy to compute the pairwise distances, and the `squareform` function to get back a regular symmetric matrix, that would otherwise be the triangular flattened:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

similarities = dict()
for cat, group in df.groupby("category"):
    a = tuple(row.vecs for _, row in group.iterrows())
    b = np.array(a)
    sim_mat = squareform(1 - pdist(b, metric='cosine'))
    similarities[cat] = sim_mat

[print(k, v, sep='\n') for k, v in similarities.items()]
```

```
a
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
b
[[0.         0.70710678]
 [0.70710678 0.        ]]
```

Comment: did you mean g[i] to be group[i]?

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake there, I edited the answer. This should work now

Comment: thank you! Is there an easy way to add them back into the dataframe?

Comment: never mind, I simply ordered the original dataframe by category prior to creating the similarities dict.  Then I casted the values in the dictionary to lists of lists and then added it to the dataframe, which I believe should work.